# Git submodule track branch or default

Tags: git, repository

I know that git submodule can track active branch on superproject, but I want something more complex. For simplicity lets say i have 2 repos: 
 **ProjectX** 
 **SharedSources**
 SharedSources is a submodule of ProjectX. 
 ProjectX will have master, development and few feature branches with name of the tasks. 
 SharedSources will have development etc branches created only if there will be need for it, which will be very rare.
If I use default branch tracking then submodule will try tracking branch "features/task_12141" which rarely will exist. What I want is something like an "if ... else" or something like that. If branch with the same name exists then use it, if not then try development, and if not then master.
 Is it possible? If not, what workarounds can you recommend?